# "understand" or "understood"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, tenses

When I explain something to my friend and I want to make sure they got what I said, what should I say?

- "Do you understand?"
- "Did you understand?"
- "Have you understood?"

etc.

Comment: All of the answers seem condescending or confrontational. How do teachers do it?

Comment: @Mitch: "Any questions?"

Comment: is this correct "Did you understood"! . if its wrong can any one explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of the examples you provided would work, but note that they could appear condescending depending on the context - like you were speaking to your friend as if you were expecting him not to understand at all.

Something more informal and deferential, at least in the United States, would be *did you get all of that?* or *can I make anything more clear*?

Comment: Indeed, or even *does that make sense*?

Comment: Even more informally, you can say *see?* or *OK?*.

Comment: *Got it?* also comes to mind.

Comment: _Capisce?_ - depending on where you are

Comment: _Eh?_ If Canadian. Results unpredictable elsewhere.

Comment: @mplungjan: _Capisce_ is using the polite pronoun; I doubt you would use it for a friend.

Comment: @Kiam Ahem, You are Italian - I was not referring to Italy at all ;) _Capisce_ is American slang, used extensively in Mafia films and TV series

Comment: @mplungjan: _capisce_ is not American slang; it's a dialect word which comes from the same place Mafia comes. Still, the person used for _capisce_ is third person singular.

Comment: @Kiam - using Capisce outside Italy to a non-Italian or an expat Italian, is definitely slang and tongue-in-cheek

Comment: @mplungjan: Using _capisce_ to mean _understand_ (which is the meaning of Italian _capisce_) is like saying _merde_ to mean _shit_. I don't think that using a foreign word instead of an English word is considered slang.

Comment: @Kiam Stubborn Much?  [books, 1950-2008](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Capisce%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) | [Urban Dictionary](http://capisce.urbanup.com/2393384) | [online slang dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/definition+of/capisce) | [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capisce)

Answer (score 0):

Any of these. Colloquially, the question is most commonly

```
Understand?
```

and the reply

```
Understood.
```

You can also ask

```
Understood?
```

and this has a slightly different connotation from "Understand?", but I'm struggling to work out what the difference is. I'll come back and edit this if I work it out.

Comment: The most common colloquially where I am from is "does that make sense?" or "make sense?"  It is less confrontational than "understand" (maybe it implies that, if the listener doesn't understand, it is because the speaker was not making any sense).

Comment: @Cosmonaut: Yes, I think you're right. I think the use of "understand?" (and even more, "understood?"), though colloquial, is only used when there is a power relationship - the higher status talking to the lower.